# finding a constant runtime algorithm to calculate a recursive summation

Tags: sequences-and-series, algorithms, asymptotics, recursive-algorithms

Suppose we have a sequence of integers $A_n$ where $A_0$, ..., $A_{k=1}$ < $50$, and for each subsequent term in the sequence, $A_i = A_{i-1}b_1 + A_{i-2}b_2 +... + A_{i-k}b_k$. ($A_0$ through $A_{k-1}$ and all $b_i$ (where i is 1 through k) are givens. I am to devise an algorithm that computes $A_n \mod 50$ and would run in a constant time (treat k as a constant), but I'm having a bit of a trouble solving this.

I get that since each $A_i$ is given by k numbers preceding it, and every $A_j$ (regardless of whether they were original 'given' numbers or subsequent terms) has 50 different possible values, there must be $50^k$ different possible ways to get $A_i$, but since all $A_j$ are modded by $50$, $A_i$ should in fact only have 50 different possible values. So I don't quite understand this discrepancy, and I'm further unsure of how to use this fact (if at all) to find the algorithm that runs in a constant time.

*Arithmetic operations on numbers of size O(log n) are done in constant time.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no really constant algorithm, because we need at the very least to read $n$, which is already $O(\log n)$.

There is an algorithm that uses $O(1)$ arithmetic operations with numbers of order $O(n)$ and $O(1)$ other operations. Say $\vec B_i = \langle A_{i - k}, A_{i - k + 1}, \ldots, A_{i - 1}\rangle$. Note that we can find $A_i$ in constant time if we know $\vec B_i$.

There are only $50^k$ possible values for $\vec B_i$, and if $\vec B_i = \vec B_j$ then $\vec B_{i + x} = \vec B_{j + x}$ for any $x \geq 0$.
So for some $p, q < 50^k$ we have $\vec B_p = \vec B_{p + q}$ and thus $\vec B_i = \vec B_{i + c\cdot q}$ for any $i \geq p$, $c > 0$. We can find such $p$ and $q$ in constant time by brute force. In other words, $A_i$ is periodic with both period and pre-period part having length of at most $50^k$, and we can find these lengths in constant time.

Now, we can write $n = t + c\cdot q$ where $p \leq t < p + q$, and thus get $\vec B_n = \vec B_t$.
We can find $\vec B_t$ in constant time, and from it find $A_n$ in constant time.

The only non-constant time is to find $t$, and to do it we need to read $n$ and perform some arithmetic on it, which takes $O(\log n)$ time. If we say that arithmetic on input-size numbers is constant time, then this algorithm runs in $O(1)$.

The discrepancy you found is because $A_i = A_j$ doesn't imply $A_{i + 1} = A_{j + 1}$, so we need to know more than $1$ previous element to find next, and there are more than $50$ different values they can take.

Comment: oh! I know that we can get log n using fast exponentiation, but I was trying to get a better algorithm and it was suggested that there would be a "better" algorithm...

Comment: apparently there should be an algorithm that doesn’t use matrix multiplication at all, but I'm not sure how—that's the problem

Comment: Well, we can use periodicity (updated answer), but we really can't get better than $O(\log n)$, because we need to read $n$. Or we need to use some model of computation that allows us manipulate with large numbers in constant time.

Comment: thank you, that clears up so many things (and yes, I'm really sorry to not have mentioned that arithmetic on numbers of O(log n) size take constant time)!

Comment: I am still a little bit confused though on how we have B_p = B_(p+q) —it it because if p+q go over 50^k we'd be "going back" the cycle? and do you mean t is actually the c>0 you mention? Sorry, I think I kind of get it, but at the same time I'm quite confused. From the example you gave it seems like the period won't necessarily be 50^k, so when actually will it be 50^k? and what do you mean by a pre-period part?

Comment: Yes, if we write first $50^k + 1$ values of $\vec B$ then at least two of them will coincide by pigeonhole principle. Say first of them is number $p$ and second $p + q$. Yes, $t$ is actually $c$, sorry for typo.

Comment: Yes, period is at most $50^k$, but can be smaller. It's a question about matrix ring - we have matrix $C$ in ring $M_k(\mathbb Z_{50})$, and we are interested in finding min $q > 0$ s.t. $C^q = C^{2q}$. It's obvious that $q \leq |M_k(\mathbb Z_{50})|$ but I am not sure if we can reach this bound. Pre-period part is part before period starts - we can easily have say $A_3 = 4$ but $A_i \neq 4$ for $i > 3$.

Comment: Note that we can dramatically speed up solving the problem by doing two separate computations - getting $A_n \mod 25$ and $A_n \mod 2$. We can then use the Chinese Remainder Theorem to piece the two back together. Still constant time, but a lot faster in practice.

Comment: oh and also how exactly are you using that if Bi = Bj then B_(i+x) = B_(j+x)? how do you know this, and by this you mean that each Bi is distinct right?

Comment: $\vec B_i$ is vector of $k$ values of $A$, they are not all distinct. We can find $\vec B_{i + 1}$ from $\vec B_i$ by removing the first coordinate and adding combination of coordinates as the last, so $\vec B_i = \vec B_j$ implies $\vec B_{i + 1} = \vec B_{j + 1}$, and iterating this we get $B_{i + x} = B_{j + x}$.

Comment: I got that now, thank you.

Comment: um back to the period being at most 50^k and the matrix rings though, I haven't really learnt the concept and while I'm trying to learn about it, it's taking a little while. do you happen to have other ways to explain the period being <= 50^k?

Comment: Answer text doesn't refer to matrices: we note that if $\vec B_i = \vec B_j$ then period divides $i - j$, and from pigeonhole principle this will happen for some $k \leq i < j \leq k + 50^k$. I guessed matrices could be used if we want to check if there is case with period $k^50$, or if actually period is always shorter.